# How do I change the content between tags in java?

Tags: java, regex, replaceall, fix-protocol

I am searching for a regex in which I can look for certain tags in FIX and then add info to them.
I thought to refer to the tags as a string and search it in a regex using the ReplaceAll method. However, I don't know how do it when I don't want to replace the string in the regex but the string after it.(meaning the content in the tag).

Comment: Just out of curiosity : is there a special reason to use regex instead of a FIX library? You are probably only dealing with the messages in a log file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the [FIX protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Financial_Information_eXchange) body is a set of `name=value` pairs separated by [SOH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#SOH) (0x01) characters, and you want to replace the value, you can use [zero-width positive lookbehind](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#special) pattern.

Example: To replace value of tag `49`

```
body = body.replaceAll("(?<=\u000149=)[^\u0001]*",
                       Matcher.quoteReplacement("new value"));
```

*Explanation*

```
(?<=           The matched value must be preceded by:  
  \u0001         SOH field delimiter
  49             Tag number
  =              Separating equal sign
)
[^\u0001]*     Matches value, e.g. everything up to the following SOH field delimiter
```

---

If you need to add text before/after/around the existing test, just insert the matched text, using the `$0` reference, which also means you shouldn't use `quoteReplacement()` to escape literal text, but you'd have to escape any special characters yourself.

```
body = body.replaceAll("(?<=\u000149=)[^\u0001]*",
                       "new text before $0 new text after"));
```

Comment: Nitpick: Please note that the first tag in the message is not preceded by SOH. But should be pretty uncommon to replace its value since it represents the FIX version.

Comment: I was about to type the same, but I can imagine hubs might do something like that @ChristophJohn.

Comment: @Andreas. This code is good but I need to add content to the tag and not to replace it. How can I refer to the existing content in the regex?

Comment: @TziporahMualem Added solution for that to answer.